Find number of solution to an equation using generating functions
I need to find the number of integer solution to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=30$ such that $x_i\geq0$ and $x_1\leq5, x_2\leq10, x_3\leq15, x_4\leq21$
I was able to come up with the generating functions for each of the variables, and multiply them (because we want all conditions to happen at once):
$$(1+x+...+x^5)(1+x+...+x^{10})(1+x+...+x^{15})(1+x+...+x^{21})$$
Then using the formula for sum of finite geometric series:
$$(\frac{1-x^6}{1-x})(\frac{1-x^{11}}{1-x})(\frac{1-x^{16}}{1-x})(\frac{1-x^{22}}{1-x})=\frac{(1-x^6)(1-x^{11})(1-x^{16})(1-x^{22})}{(1-x)^4}$$
And i'm not sure how to move on. I can multiply out the terms in the numerator but i'm not sure what it will give me, there must be a simpler way. Thanks to the helpers!
The answers given in the linked question do not really help me... for example, the first answer "gets stuck" exactly where I got stuck. I expect to find a closed form answer, and I don't want skipping steps, I want the direct continuation of my attempt (or an entirely different perspective).

why dont you use wolfram or sage math tools to calculate the coefficient of $x^{30}$

Because that's cheating...^

Personally, I have come to regard the use of a computer algebra system to expand products of polynomials as a basic tool of the conbinatorialist, much as hand-held calculators in the classroom used to be regarded as cheating and are now accepted.  In other words, I used to feel guilty, but I got over it. ;-)

Well of course I'd be happy to do that. The thing is that the instructors won't be so happy if I do it in the exam)))
But anyways, I was able to solve the question using inclusion-exclusion, it wasn't so bad.
